User cannot copy file to their own Drive shared by a service-account
We are trying to have users copy files that were shared with them by a service account, but when we use the files.copy method it responds with a 404. The token we have from the user has the drive.file scope (which is the desired non-sensitive scope).
We could copy directly to users drive after having them give access to the service account, but we want to avoid that because the files will be counting towards the service account quota.
Also, those files are Google native files, (gdocs, gspreadsheet, etc) that can't be downloaded and re-uploaded.
My question is if I can figure out why when I try to copy to users drive using their own token, that has been shared with them from a service account, Im getting a 404. But also if there's a different approach I can take.
Thank you

Users should not be granting access to a service account.  service accounts should only be used to access accounts you the developer control.   Google native files can be downloaded using export.
